# Does closed Alexandrov space admit a bi-Lipschitz embedding into $\mathbb R^N$?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

As the title says.
Let $A^n$ be an $n$-dimensional closed Alexandrov space. Does it admit a bi-Lipschitz embedding into Euclidean space $\mathbb R^N$ for sufficiently large $N$?

I know there are some spaces that do not admit such an embedding; for example, a theorem by Pansu says that:

> The Heisenberg group
>   equipped with the Carnot-Caratheodory distance does not biLipschitz embed into $\mathbb R^n$,
>   for any $n$.

Comment: The Heisenberg group doesn't embed isometrically with respect to Euclidean distance, but Enrico Le Donne proved that there are Nash-type embeddings that preserve the length of every curve!  See http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.1623 .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See Distance embedding (27.5) in [our book](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1577084/the-book.pdf)

Comment: Dear Anton, are chapters 13 and 15 available?

Comment: @Suvrit, everything which is nearly ready is there, check it time to time, maybe more sections will appear. If you really-really need some sections I could send it with a "read on your own risk" notice --- send me an e-mail.

Comment: Thanks Anton. I'll email if you if this need arises (I'm mostly interested in the theory of first-order approximation in metric spaces, and in particular in CAT(0) spaces and slight perturbations of these spaces.

Answer (score 2):

In my preprint "Bi-Lipschitz embeddings of SRA-free spaces into Euclidean spaces" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.02477) I prove the quantitative version of this statement.

> Theorem 2.
>   For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $k < 0$ and $R > 0$ there exist $D > 0$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying the following.
>   For every $n$-dimensional Alexandrov space of curvature $\ge k$ and every $x \in X$
>   there exists an embedding $\phi:B_R(x) \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^N$ which 
>   bi-Lipschitz distortion does not exceed $D$.
>
> For $n \in N$ there exist $D_0 > 0$ and $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
>   every $n$-dimensional Alexandrov space of non-negative curvature 
>   allows an embedding into $\mathbb{N}^{N_0}$ which 
>   bi-Lipschitz distortion does not exceed $D_0$.

Comment: Was this ever published?

Comment: @TomTheQuant No I haven't published it. I'm out of academy so it's hard to find any motivation to deal with journals.